# How to determine the first function that gets called when running a program in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a project that already has lots of files and functions. When I run the program, it executes properly, but I want to know how to find out the first function that gets called when we initially run the application.

More info:

- When you run the application, it opens up a small window, asks the users to input some data (like username, password, etc), and waits for the users' data
- The call stack is empty, so that doesn't help
- The call hierarchy isn't helpful either, since this is a big project
- This is a C++ project, and I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: What do you consider first?  Where the program actually starts, or do you want to know about global data being initialized?  IIRC, the standard considers the program to start when `main` is called.

Comment: globals initialization can call functions before main. And with multiple compilation unit the order in which that happens is undefined and may change from build to build.

Comment: @NathanOliver Where the program actually starts. I completely forgot about the main function for some reason. There is no main function, but there is WinMain, which I'm guessing is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @JohanvonAdden Yeah WinWain will be where the programs logic starts

Comment: The very first function that is called at program startup is the EntryPoint pointed at in the EXE's PE header, which the OS calls directly after creating the new process.  That function is then responsible for initializing the runtime library, initializing globals, etc, and then finally calling the user's `main()`/`WinMain()` function, depending on which one the runtime uses.

Comment: Don't start with F5, use Debug > Step Into instead. The debugger breaks on the first statement that it has debug info for. So not the runtime library initialization and DllMain() 
 entrypoints, the kind of code that actually executes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the main function (or the WinMain function in my case).

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)